# Explicit password and email validation in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity, why needed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am big fan of Adam Freeman's books. At his Pro Asp.net mvc 5 platform, in chapter 13, page 325, the following code confused me. Does anyone have the explanation why he used the email and password validation explicitly?

The call `this.UserManager.UpdateAsync(user)` should return a result with same errors generated by `this.UserManager.UserValidator.ValidateAsync(user)` and `this.UserManager.PasswordValidator.ValidateAsync(password)`. Is he not doing the same thing twice? Or there is a special purpose?

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(string id, string email, string password)
    {
        AppUser user = await this.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (user != null)
        {
            user.Email = email;
            IdentityResult validEmail = await this.UserManager.UserValidator.ValidateAsync(user);
            if (!validEmail.Succeeded)
            {
                this.AddErrorsFromResult(validEmail);
            }

            IdentityResult validPass = null;
            if (password != string.Empty)
            {
                validPass = await this.UserManager.PasswordValidator.ValidateAsync(password);
                if (validPass.Succeeded)
                {
                    user.PasswordHash = this.UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(password);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.AddErrorsFromResult(validPass);
                }
            }

            if ((validEmail.Succeeded && validPass == null)
                || (validEmail.Succeeded && password != string.Empty && validPass.Succeeded))
            {
                IdentityResult result = await this.UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                this.AddErrorsFromResult(result);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "User not found");
        }

        return this.View(user);
    }

private AppUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<AppUserManager>();
        }
    }
private void AddErrorsFromResult(IdentityResult result)
    {
        foreach (string error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, the only person who can really answer that is Adam Freeman, isn't it? Likely, there's some contact info for him in the book, somewhere, so I'd recommend reaching out to him directly.

Answer (score 1):

in source code of identity UserManager class  UpdateAsync method is like this:

```
public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> UpdateAsync(TUser user)
        {
            ThrowIfDisposed();
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
            }

            var result = await UserValidator.ValidateAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return result;
            }
            await Store.UpdateAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return IdentityResult.Success;
        }
```

that calls `UserValidator.ValidateAsync(user)` method for validating that username is not illegal or user not registered before with a different Owner Id and does not care for validating Email address or password string.  if you want to validate passwords and do your custom checks you must create custom validators .
you can find  [Default UserValidator source code here](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.0.0-rtm-140224/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserValidator.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core)